# DllImport:RegisterCallback(pbc, url) and BindMonikerToStream(pmk, pbc)

Tags: vb.net, winforms, com, webbrowser-control, dllimport

I'm trying to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362922/windows-forms-webbrowswer-control-with-idownloadmanager) post so I can get the URL of file downloads that are not exposed with the HTML or the webbrowser.navigate event. The code is incomplete in that example though. The answer makes reference to

```
RegisterCallback(pbc, url)
BindMonikerToStream(pmk, pbc)
```

which are not defined. I can't find proper definitions for those methods online. There are some, but with different arguments. pinvoke.net doesn't list RegisterCallback or BindMonikerToStream, but DOES have CreateBindCtx.

Does anyone know how those two should be defined?

Comment: Have you checked the link that he provided in the question?

Comment: Yes, the link is to a simple example of a file downloader that he was extending, which prompted the question. If the answer and these functions were in the example, he wouldn't have needed to get an answer. I have searched the code in the example/link and no reference is made.