# SQL Agent Job running .NET C# WinForms application with a WebBrowser control. Trying to send key strokes

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, sendkeys, sql-agent-job

As the title suggest, I have a .NET C# Winforms app with a WebBrowser control. I use it to download a (dynamically generated) Excel file from a website, and it is working just fine. I have to use a WebControl as per my employer request.

When I use a SQL Agent Job to run a SSIS package with an Execute Process Task to execute the app, it fails (as in the file is not downloaded). If I run the SSIS package it works, correctly. The difference is with the SQL Job the app window is not showing.

When the WebBrowser control shows the Open - Download - Close dialog, I send key strokes (Alt + S) to save the file and then close the dialog. When the SQL Job runs the app, the keystrokes never make it to the WebBroser.

I have tried sending keys using SendKeys.SendWait, and also using User32 dll to get the dialogs and buttons handles and then SendMessage/PostMessage (tried both) to send the key strokes. Both methods work correctly as an exe, and as a SSIS package. And both methods fail when running the SQL Job.

I also have tried overriding the download manager as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362922/windows-forms-webbrowswer-control-with-idownloadmanager) without success. To be honest I don't know what to do to get the dynamically generated Excel file the app have to download when the execution reach the overrided Download method. The link I get when debugging the Download method is not the link to the file.

```
/// <summary>
/// Return S_OK (0) so that IE will stop to download the file itself. 
/// Else the default download user interface is used.
/// </summary>
public int Download(IMoniker pmk, IBindCtx pbc, uint dwBindVerb, int grfBINDF, IntPtr pBindInfo,
                    string pszHeaders, string pszRedir, uint uiCP)
{
    // Get the display name of the pointer to an IMoniker interface that specifies the object to be downloaded.
    string name;
    pmk.GetDisplayName(pbc, null, out name);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
    {
        Uri url;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(name, UriKind.Absolute, out url))
        {
            if ( FileDownloading != null )
            {
                 FileDownloading(this, new FileDownloadEventArgs(url));
            }
            return Constants.S_OK;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is the Response Header when I click the button to download the file:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xlsx"

Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
```

I can provide with the app code if requested.

Any help would be really appreciated. Excuse my poor english.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This sounds silly. Why do you have to use a web control to download and immediately save the webpage? Since SQL agent is running as a service you'll give yourself a headache trying to work with a windows forms application.

I'd either create a separate non interactive console application which does the download and saving, or if reusability is the motivation- split the application in two: one exe with the windows form, and another exe with the download logic. The first exe can reference the other exe to access its public classes.

Comment: It is silly. Unfortunately I am not allowed to use Fiddler in the dev machine, and I have been requested to use the WebBrowser class. I am trying to implement this solution but I am kind of stuck: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362922/windows-forms-webbrowswer-control-with-idownloadmanager